# Write a Unit Test for function without return value

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing

I have a function that takes a link as input, then requests values, then puts them in an available list, this function doesn't return anything, how can I write test cases for them?
For example:

```
list = []
def myfunc(link):
    [code block]
    list.append(value)
```

Comment: Your test function needs to reset the global variable `list` to `[]`, then call `myfunc`, then verify the contents of that global variable. BTW, I'd recommend using a different name for that variable, as `list` is a "reserved keyword" (which you are overriding when you use this variable name).

Comment: can i reset the variable list to [] in testing module bro ?

Comment: + very bad naming practice to name a list 'list'

Comment: i mean list [] then call function in file test.py ?

Comment: Sure. You'll just need to declare it `global` in the test function.

Comment: @Learningisamess no bro, its just an expample

Comment: Oh, you want to implement the test function in a different file?

Comment: yes @bbbbbbbbb i want to implement the test function in a different file, like a testing file

Comment: You'll need to reload this file over and over. On each load, this variable will be essentially set to an empty list. You will need to import both the function and the global variable, and check the contents of the global variable after you call the function.

Comment: i think i got it, thanks

Comment: That's what classes are for btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is very clean, but this would work:
I made a new file to separate the production code from the testing code.
I imported the list (in my code it's l) and test on it.
My main.py:

```
from typing import Any

l = []

def myfunc(link: Any) -> None:
    my_actual_value = "my_expected_value"
    l.append(my_actual_value)
```

My main_test.py:

```
import unittest

import main
from main import myfunc

class TestMyFunc(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        main.l = []

    def test_my_func(self) -> None:
        # Given
        some_link = "some_link"
        my_expected_value = ["my_expected_value"]
        # When
        myfunc(some_link)
        # Then
        assert my_expected_value == main.l

    def test_my_func2(self) -> None:
        # Given
        some_link = "some_link2"
        my_expected_value = ["my_expected_value"]
        # When
        myfunc(some_link2)
        # Then
        assert my_expected_value == main.l
```

Comment: i'm tried it in my test code and it helped, thank u so much

Answer (score 1):

Generally it's not great to use global variables. I'd recommend using something like a class. eg:

```
class Whatevs:
    def __init__(self):
        self.list = []

    def my_func(self,link):
        [code block]
        self.list.append(value)
```

Then in your test you can do something like:

```
instance = Whatevs()
instance.my_func()
assert instance.list == [whatever it should be]
```

Also, I'd recommend reading PEP8. It just has some stuff about naming that you might find useful

Comment: Hopefully he can change the code to better code... it's a better way.

Comment: yes, i dont want to change the code

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb it's easy to forget that there are people behind the text. Please remember that all the people who answer things here are actually trying to help folks and build a useful resource.  

In any case, best practice is to test the code you write yourself which implies some control over the code under test. When you dont test your own code then all sorts of weird things (like nasty global variables) slip into the code. Generally when code is written to make testing easy it makes a whole lot of other things easy as well.

Comment: I think that the main problem which this dude faces, is that he is required to test someone else's code, not under his control (which means that he cannot change it).

Answer (score 1):

Import the list, clear it, run the function and then check it's value:

```
from my_module import list, myfunc

def test_myfunc():
  list.clear()
  myfunc()
  assert list == [1, 2, 3]
```